# If pogonotrophy means to grow a beard, is there a term for shaving a beard?

Tags: single-word-requests, etymology, word-usage, antonyms, greek

If *pogonotrophy* means "to grow a beard", is there a term for shaving a beard?

How would you use *pogonotrophy* in a sentence? And if there is an antonym for this word, how would you use it in a sentence?

Comment: _Pogonotomy_ uses the same root as _appendectomy, hysterectomy, microtome,_ etc. Scientific Greejk usually uses the O-grade stem _tom-_ from the same [PIE root *tem-](http://web.archive.org/web/20080629055757/http://www.bartleby.com/61/roots/IE525.html) as the Greek verb τέμνω 'I cut'.

Comment: I would also suggest that the insulting act by Hanun in 2Samuel 10:4 against the servants of King David was an act of hemi-pogonotomy. David's remedy for the victims was pogonotrophic retreat.

Answer (score 3):

The opposite of *pogonotrophy* is of course [*pogonotomy*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/239304).  The OED provides these citations, amongst others:

- 1897 Columbus (Ohio) Dispatch Jan., ― Pogonotomy is what the Greeks used to call the gentle art of self-shaving.
- 1942 Berrey & Van den Bark Amer. Thes. Slang §125/3 ― Pogonotomy, shaving.
- 1960 Times 28 Sept. (Advertising Suppl.) p. iii/2 ― This is the age, in fact, of pogonotomy.
- 1966 J. S. Cox Dict. Hairdressing & Wigmaking 119/1 ― Pogonotomy, beard-cutting or shaving.
- 1966 Daily Mail 29 Oct. 1/1 ― This week’s picture of Beatle George Harrison wearing a moustache-and a particularly sad, droopy looking one at that-caught students of pogonotrophy the world over in two minds.

Apparently, people get these two words mixed up.  On [World Wide Words](http://www.worldwidewords.org/weirdwords/ww-pog1.htm) it says of *pogonotrophy*:

> Do not — as a British journalist did some years ago — confuse this useful word with *pogonotomy*. Both originate in the Greek word *pogon*, a beard, but the latter ends in *‑tomia*, cutting, and so is the word for trimming one’s beard, or shaving, the exact opposite of the writer’s intention.
>
> *Pogonotrophy*, on the other hand, ends with Greek *trophe*, nourishment, so its literal sense is “beard feeding”, though it it may better be glossed as growing a beard or cultivating one.

This article titled “Pogonotomy versus Pogonotrophy” in [The Pharmaceutical Journal](http://www.pharmaceutical-journal.com/opinion/blogs/pogonotomy-versus-pogonotrophy/10036965.blog) presents the following example sentence:

> It has been estimated that the average clean-shaven man fritters away some 3,500 hours of his life at his pogonotomy.

Not only does that article feature *pogonotomy* and *pogonotrophy*, it also mentions *pogonophile*, *pogonotopiary*, *pogonophobes*, and *pogonologists*.

These are all extreme fancy words with little to no practical use in normal conversational contexts.  If I were you, I’d stick with [*pogo sticks*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pogo_stick) or [*Pogo strips*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pogo_(comic_strip)), myself.

Comment: Are they pronounced like this? poh-guh-NAH'-truh-fee / poh-guh-NAH'-tuh-mee

Comment: @Whip I suppose that would be one way of expressing it, yes. Personally I prefer IPA. Thing is, no matter how you say it, almost no one will understand these rare words.

Comment: I finally found this: http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=75mig3P8PnQ

Comment: And this: http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=iPz7Ysb5FCE